# GridView1.SelectedRow returning nothing

Tags: vb.net, gridview, postback

My problem is that in the below code, the SelectedRow property returns nothing. I manually bind items to GridView at runtime and autogeneratecolumns and autogenerateselectbutton properties are true.

I think the problem is about having a PostBack when the Select command is clicked.

Thanks a lot.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
        Session("ContactID") = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(0).Text()
        Response.Redirect("~/ContactAddress.aspx")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The row you want is accessible via e (the GridViewCommandEventArgs parameter), specifically the value of e.CommandArgument which will have the row index :

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) :

> To determine the index of the row that
>   raised the event, use the
>   CommandArgument property of the event
>   argument that is passed to the event.
>   The ButtonField class automatically
>   populates the CommandArgument property
>   with the appropriate index value. For
>   other command buttons, you must
>   manually set the CommandArgument
>   property of the command button. For
>   example, you can set the
>   CommandArgument to <%#
>   Container.DataItemIndex %> when the
>   GridView control has no paging
>   enabled.

Comment: As a temporary solution, I used the SelectedIndexChanged event to get what I want, CommandArgument property wasn't really helping. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The selected row is in the GridViewCommandEventArgs parameter.

Comment: The row hasn't been selected yet.

Answer (score 0):

Besides adding the CommandArgument, you need to change your code to the following.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
Dim rowNumber As Integer = e.CommandArgument
Dim ContactId As Integer = GridView1.Rows(rowNumber).Cells(0).Text
    Session("ContactID") = ContactId
    Response.Redirect("~/ContactAddress.aspx")
End Sub
```